# How to disable startup connection to a 'dead' server?

Tags: network

My mac (OsX 10.7) try to connect to a disabled server at startup.
How to remove /delete this auto connection (that fail each time) ?
Thanks

Comment: You might want to provide some more background on what your computer is trying to do. Connecting to a disabled server doesn't explain what kind of connection, how do you know this is happening, etc.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My guess would be that there is a login item for the dead server. To Remove it access Systems preferences via:

`` -> `System Preferences` -> `Users & Groups` -> `Choose your user` -> `Login items` ->

Select the Dead Server and press "-" to remove it.

[image: Login Items]

Comment: This worked for me.  A slightly different variant I had was, I had a folder on a remote server (that was no longer connected) in my Favorites column on Finder, so instead of FS showing up in the example above, I had a folder called "My_Photos" that I needed to remove.

Comment: Is there a "yes, I know you can't connect to the local NAS because we're not home right now, so can you please shut up about it for more than 2 minutes at a time?" button or do I have to remove and re-add these items every time I leave my desk?

Answer (score 3):

I solved this by going to Finder -> Go -> Connect to Server (command-K).  In there was a "Favorite Server" that was the culprit.  Removed it and the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

On newer Mac hardware,  you may also get this from the Remote Disk settings.
You can fix this by unchecking the Remote Disk box in the Finder Favorites under devices.