# How to prevent an automatic network share connection at startup?

Tags: macos, mac, network, startup

**Problem Synopsis:** I have a WiFi router that can connect to a USB storage device and then allow access to that device over WiFi. I had once connected my Mac (OS X Lion 10.7.4) to such a storage device using the Finder's "Connect to Server" option. I am no longer using that setup but every time I login to my Mac (after a reboot) I get an error message that says:

[image: There was a problem connection to router]

*router was the name I gave to my network share drive.*

**Attempted Fixes:**

1. I have explored my login items but cannot find an item that connects to "router". In fact the only login item I have is for iTunesHelper. This solution was suggested [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/53404/how-to-disable-startup-connection-to-a-dead-server).
2. I have also cleared the list of "Recent Servers" from the Finder's "Connect to Server" menu.
3. I removed the username/password for "router" from my keychain.

None of these solved the problem and my Mac still shows that message every time I login after a reboot.

**Actual Question:** Does anyone know how to disable this automatic connection at startup or remove this particular device from that list?